# Pentaho Join table values

Tags: sql, pentaho, kettle

I'm rookie at kettle pentaho and Querys. What i'm trying to do is check if value A, in file 1 is in file 2.

I've got 2 files, that i export from my DB:

File 1:

```
Row1, Row2
 A      3
 B      5
 C      99
 Z      65
```

File 2:

```
Row1, Row2
 A      3
 D      11
 E      22
 Z      65
```

And i want to create one file output:

File Output

```
Row1, Row2
 A      3
 Z      65
```

What i'm doing: 2 files input, merge join, but no file output. Something missing here.

Any suggestion will be great!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the two streams joined by a "Merge join" step, which allows you to set freely the join keys (in your case it seems like you want both fields to be used), and also what type of join, Inner, Left Outer, Right outer or Full outer.

Comment: Thanks you two! It was a great help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream lookup for that. Start with the file input for file 1, then create a stream lookup step that uses the input stream for file 2 as its lookup stream. Now just match the columns and you can add the column from file 2 to your data stream.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort both files in Ascending Order
2. use the MergeJoin step to join both tables on the sorted field (this case Row1)
3. use select vales step to delete unwanted field produced as result of the join
4. output your result using the dummy step or whatever output you prefer

this should work fine